# QML: How to get the total height of a Repeater?

Tags: qt, qml, qt5, repeater

I have a Repeater but the Repeater's children have varying heights I can't determine myself. However, **I need to find the total height of all the Repeater's children**. I know I can loop through all the children and add up all their heights but I feel that's incredibly inefficient and was hoping there would be a better way. Here is some sample code I'm using to test:

```
import QtQuick 2.10
import QtQuick.Window 2.10

Window {
id: root
width: 320
height: 580

Component.onCompleted: loadData()

function loadData() {
    var len, i, repeater_data
    len = 3
    repeater_data = new Array(len)
    for (i = 0; i < len; i++) {
        repeater_data[i] = { "name": i, "height": (Math.random() * 100 + 50) }
    }
    repeater.model = repeater_data
}

Flickable {
    id: mainFlick
    anchors.fill: parent
    contentHeight: mainColumn.height
    Column {
        id: mainColumn
        width: parent.width

        Repeater {
            id: repeater
            width: parent.width
            model: []
            delegate: Column {
                id: repeaterItem
                width: parent.width
                Text {
                    text: modelData["name"] + " - Height: " + modelData["height"]
                    height: modelData["height"]
                }
            } // repeaterItem
        } // repeater
    } // mainColumn
} // mainFlick
} // root
```

I've tried various applications of the 'childrenRect' property to no avail.

Comment: Repeater is an Item so it has no geometric meaning, the Repeater only creates other items based on a model so this will not give you any information about the geometry, so unfortunately you will have to add. Why do you think adding is inefficient?

Comment: @eyllanesc Thank you. It's simply that I will have large numbers of items and a sizable number of repeaters on the same page (they are collapsible to save space) so I was worried that looping and adding when I need the height might create an unwanted delay.

Comment: How many is a large number? If there are hundreds I do not think there is a delay since the heights of each item are inline (that is, they are not calculated, they are only recalculated when they are necessary), if there are millions there you would have to give a deal adequate, but I think you have only hundreds of items.

Comment: `Repeater` is not a _layout_, so as you are using `Column` without `spacing` which groups the items of `Repeater`, the height of `Column` is the total height of `Repeater`.

Answer (score 2):

I was searching for an answer for this question and found that you can use this

```
mainColumn.childrenRect.height
```

which will provide the total height of the children of column or width of totatl row children in my case.

Answer (score 0):

If `len = 3`, I have for example:

- 0 - Height: 86.47358953069201
- 1 - Height: 147.20601108198989
- 2 - Height: 100.03074850782205

If I add to the root item the following code:

```
focus: true
Keys.onPressed: {
    console.log(mainFlick.contentHeight)
    console.log(mainColumn.height)
}
```

I obtain:

```
qml: 333.71034912050396
qml: 333.71034912050396
```

Isn't it what is looked for?